# How to distribute licensed copy of VMWare Fusion 6 with Ubuntu VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I bought VMWare Fusion 6 and made a VM of Ubuntu with a special set of packages installed. Now, I was to distribute this VM to some end-users. It is my understanding that these users can download VM Player from VMware for free (non-commercial) use. However, how do I "export" my VM to send to them? I've made snapshots, but I don't think that is that same thing.

Comment: The copy is for you! If you "distribute" it, I think it will be violation of terms of use....e.g. If I purchase one copy of windows and I make a VM out of it and give it to 1000 people, they can technically use Windows without ever buying it...Refer VMWare's license agreement for further info...Other than that, I will answer the question

Comment: I see what you mean, but that is why I chose Ubuntu, since it is a completely free OS

Comment: Ohh yes...I just wanted to remind you in case you have some paid software onto it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is with the OS (in your case Linux) powered down click on VM and select manage then select cleanup ( you should cleanup you OS on a regular basis ) and if it recommends to cleanup do it , Then go to edit this virtual machine click on your hard drive select utilities and defragment the hard drive , Then click on VM again click on manage again and select clone and it will take you threw a wizard and selelect create a full clone . After that is all done you can use your favorite compression program ( .zip .7z .rar ) to make it a more manageable size for transportation

Answer (score 2):

Typically all files for a VM should reside in same directory except for virtual disk. If its not, configure VM to have it in same folder.
Then, give all these file and the virtual disk files to users and it should run fine AFAIK